# Bitcoin transfeered to wrong address

Tags: transactions

I'm new to copay.  I just transferred money to a bitcoin address but for some reason, Copay transferred it to my own account.  I had to pay a miners fee for this which cost a lot of money.  How can I contest this?  I put in the correct address but it did not go there.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not confusing this with change? If the inputs to the transaction were greater than what you wanted to pay, some of that will be paid back to your own wallet as change.

Answer (score 0):

Its on Copays end so open a support ticket with them and see if they will refund you the miners fee and the fee for the bitcoin to go to the correct address. Purely an issue on their end and nothing you can really do on the Bitcoin network.